# Node.js res.render when task completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm making Node.js Application using Express.js. I have a page which render some datas from other site. so I use with Cheerio.js and It's not problem, but the problem is I don't know how can I render when the scrapping task completed. I made a code like below, Please see.

```
var urls = [ 'http://a.com/fruits', 'http://a.com/cars', 'http://a.com/toys' ] 

function getData(){

// get html and parse, return some data.
  ...       
}

var data_set = '';

for (var i=0; i< urls.length ; i++){
     data_set += getData(urls[i]);
}

// When get all data, render <------ How can I catch when?
res.render('some_page', { data : data_set });
```

Thought some ways to do it,

**#1 - Render when** `i == urls.length`

```
for (var i=0; i< urls.length ; i++){
     data_set += getData(urls[i]);
     if( i == urls.length){
        res.render(....);
     }
}

// Result : 
// The data has not been scrapped, so the page wouldn't display data fully.
```

**#2 - callback with getData()**

```
function getData(callback){

// get html and parse, return some data.
  ...
// when complete, callback();          
}

var someHelper = 0;
getData(function(){ someHelper ++ ;});

if (someHelper == 3){
    res.render(...);
}

// If someHeper is not 3, the page would not rendered. 
// And `if statement` executed before someHelper == 3 at times ==> infinite page loading (error)
```

How can I handle this? Should I find use `Promise`?...
Please Help me with some points.

Comment: i suggest `Promise` for this

Comment: @kiro112 I don't know what is compiled template... it just some numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use either promises or async.js library up to you really...

here is how you could do it using promises

```
function getData(urlString) {
   return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
      //fetch and resolve promise with data from urlString
   });
}

var data_set = '';
var promises = [];
for (var i=0; i< urls.length ; i++){
    promises.push(function () {
        return getData(urls[i]).then(function (data) {
            data_set += data;
        });
    });
}

Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
    res.render('some_page', { data : data_set });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. but `var promises = []; and Promise.all(promises).then ...` The then() function executed before promises array filled.

Comment: no its not, each 'getData' function will be resolved during the 'Promise.all' call and later in 'then' you will have all your completed results

Answer (score 0):

Nested callbacks may help you. You can call the getData function one by one, and append content to data_set in each callback function.

```
var urls = [ 'http://a.com/fruits', 'http://a.com/cars', 'http://a.com/toys' ], data_set = '';

function getData(url, cb){

    // get html and parse, return some data.
      ...
    // call cb when downloaded contents
    cb(content);

}

getData(urls[0], function (content) {

    data_set += content;
    getData(urls[1], function (content) {

        data_set += content;
        getData(urls[2], function (content) {
            data_set += content;
            res.render('some_page', { data : data_set });
        }

    }

});
```

To avoid callback hell, you can also use module like "async", "q", "promise".